# Filtering Javascript SubArray Elements By Referencing Another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays: mainArray and allowedArray. The arrays have the following formats:

**Starting Arrays**

mainArray

```
Array(18) [ "Bill", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Bill", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
Array(18) [ "Tom", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Tom", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
Array(18) [ "Cathy", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Cathy", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
```

allowedArray

```
Array(2) [ "Tom", "Cathy" ]
```

**Desired Output**

goodArray

```
Array(18) [ "Tom", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Tom", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
Array(18) [ "Cathy", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Cathy", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
```

badArray

```
Array(18) [ "Bill", "AGLUK", "JAW", … ]
Array(18) [ "Bill", "AKI", "MONEY", … ]
```

I have tried various bits of code, all unsuccessful:

```
mainArray.forEach(function(line) {
     allowedArray.forEach(function(ID) {
       if (line[0] == ID[0]) {
       goodArray.push(line);
     }
   });
});
```

**Problem**: goodArray is always empty

Comment: Is allowed array a 2D array as well?

Comment: `goodArray = mainArray.filter(item => allowedArray.includes(item[0]));`

Comment: Thomas, that did the trick - thank you very much!

Question -- is there a "not include" function so I can put the items not overlapping into a "bad array"?

Comment: add a ! in front. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use an helper object and take the check for the array as key for the corresponding array.

```js
var array = [["Bill", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Bill", "AKI", "MONEY"], [ "Tom", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Tom", "AKI", "MONEY"], [ "Cathy", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Cathy", "AKI", "MONEY"]],
    allowedArray = ["Tom", "Cathy"],
    good = [],
    bad = [],
    temp = { true: good, false: bad };
    
array.forEach(function(line) {
    temp[allowedArray.indexOf(line[0]) !== -1].push(line);
});

console.log(good);
console.log(bad);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With newer ES it is a bit shorter with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [["Bill", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Bill", "AKI", "MONEY"], [ "Tom", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Tom", "AKI", "MONEY"], [ "Cathy", "AGLUK", "JAW"], [ "Cathy", "AKI", "MONEY"]],
    allowedArray = ["Tom", "Cathy"],
    good = [],
    bad = [],
    temp = { true: good, false: bad };
    
array.forEach(line => temp[allowedArray.includes(line[0])].push(line));

console.log(good);
console.log(bad);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Minor comment: `Array#includes` is actually ES7 (or ES2016).

Comment: Better using a ternary: `line => (allowedArray.includes(line[0])? good: bad).push(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `some` method. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
var answer = mainArray.some(a => allowedArray.indexOf(a) != -1) ? mainArray : [];
```

This will keep the entire mainArray if any of its elements are included in the allowedArray.

Edit: Misplaced 'any' for 'some'.

Comment: "any method"? What any method?

Comment: do you mean `.some()` ?

Comment: Good catch.  I misspoke. It is some, not any

Comment: Unfortunate that the desired output is not actually the desired output. :(

Answer (score 0):

If we translate the problem to english we'd get something like this:

*For each item in `mainArray`, check if its value for index 0 is present in `allowedArray`. If so, add the item to `goodArray`, otherwise add the item to `badArray`.*

This is pretty much literally translatable back to javascript:

```js
const mainArray = [
    [ "Bill", "AGLUK", "JAW"],
    [ "Bill", "AKI", "MONEY"],
    [ "Tom", "AGLUK", "JAW"],
    [ "Tom", "AKI", "MONEY"],
    [ "Cathy", "AGLUK", "JAW"],
    [ "Cathy", "AKI", "MONEY"],
];

const allowedArray = ["Tom", "Cathy"];

const goodArray = [];
const badArray = [];

// For each item in mainArray..
mainArray.forEach(function(item) {

    // check if the value for index 0 is present in allowedArray. 
    // If so...
    if (allowedArray.indexOf(item[0]) !== -1) {
        // add the item to goodArray,
        goodArray.push(item);
    // otherwise...
    } else {
        // add the item to badArray
        badArray.push(item);
    }
});

console.log({ goodArray, badArray });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
```

When shortened a little, and without the comments it could look like this:

```
mainArray.forEach((record) => allowedArray.indexOf(record[0]) !== -1
    ? goodArray.push(record)
    : badArray.push(record));
```